# regex extracting text succeeding rather than preceeding

Tags: regex

This is the expression I am currently using:

`(?<=Post Code </TD> <TD width="50%">)[\w\s\/\,]*`

It works perfectly but now I wish to select text from front of the string Post Code

`</TD> <TD width="50%">`

rahter than the text after. How do I achieve this?

Comment: `[\w\s/\,]*(?=Post Code )`

Comment: Check this desktop (offline) regular expression development tool [Expresso 3.0](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). It's free, really easy to use and a great method to learn how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and working: `[\w\s/\,]*(?=(Post Code))`